# Wavefront set of a smooth function

Tags: microlocal-analysis

I'm trying to show that the wavefront set of a function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is empty, $WF(f) = \emptyset$.

Can anyone help me prove this? This is my first exposition into wavefront sets so I have little progress with regards to workings out.

Comment: What is the definition of the wavefront set that you are using? Do you know that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is again a Schwartz function?